# SelectedItem in TabbedPage.xaml does not work Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hey everyone Good Day I have tabbed created in xaml, I prefer xaml because I have login in xaml code. My Code

Tab.xaml

```
<TabbedPage 
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsSample.Views;assembly=FormsSample"
        x:Class="FormsSample.Views.LoginPage"
        x:Name="TbPage">
     <TabbedPage.Children>
        <ContentPage x:Name="TbLog" Title="Login">
        </ContentPage>
        <ContentPage x:Name="TbSch" Title="Schedule">
        </ContentPage>
        <ContentPage x:Name="TbLis" Title="Customers">
        </ContentPage>
        </TabbedPage.Children>   
</TabbedPage>
```

Tab.xaml.cs

```
   namespace FormsSample.Views
   {
    public partial class LoginPage : TabbedPage 
    {

       private readonly TabbedPage _tbPage;
       private readonly ContentPage _tbList;
       private readonly ContentPage _tbLogn; 


       public LoginPage()
       {
        InitializeComponent ();
        _tbPage = this.FindByName<TabbedPage>("TbPage");
        _tbList = this.FindByName<ContentPage>("TbLis");
        _tbLogn = this.FindByName<ContentPage>("TbLog");
        RunTime();
        }

        private void RunTime()
        {
               _tbPage.CurrentPage = _tbLogn; 
           if (_tbPage.SelectedItem == _tbPage.Children[2])
           {
              DisplayAlert("Tab", "Hello World", "OK");
           }
         }

       }

     }
```

changing to

```
  _tbPage.SelectedItem == _tbList
```

Its similar nothing happen, How to solve this? thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry but its not directly apparent to me what you are trying to achieve? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis what am trying to achieve is USER and Administrator distinction, say if user will access that Tablist it pop up message say "You are not authorize to access the list"

Comment: Maybe another approach is better? Why not remove the tab altogether if the user can't access it?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis there are tabs that user has an access :D only one tab user arent allowed.

Comment: So, check the rights when the page is appearing and do `Children.Remove(_tbLogn);` if that is the tab you would want to give no rights to. Or turn it around and only add it when the user _does_ have right.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks but I already solve it I posted the solution :D thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be fancy but it works for me :D

```
        this.CurrentPageChanged += (o, e) => 
        {
           var i = this.Children.indexOf(this.CurrentPage); 
            if(i == 1 && UsrType == 2)
            {
                 DisplayAlert("Admin", "Administrator Privilege required!", "OK");
                 this.CurrentPage = _tbLog;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I set `SelectedItem` to `null` first, before setting it to the page I wanted to show.

Comment: Iv long abandon the form and now working on Java Android.

Comment: Yes seems like setting to null was needed to trigger something for tab to actually switch.